# asp.net core mvc controller unit testing when using TryUpdateModel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In an asp.net core application, I have a pair of controller methods that respond to an Edit action.  One for GET, which takes a string parameter for the entity id:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
```

and the other for receiving a POST of updated entity values:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]        
public async Task<IActionResult> EditSave(string id)
```

Inside the postable action method, I call

```
var bindingSuccess = await TryUpdateModelAsync(vm);
```

And that works fine.

Now, I'm trying to write a test for this, but am finding that `TryUpdateModelAsync` requires lots of things from `HttpContext` and the controller to be fleshed out.  I've tried mocking those out, but after looking at the source code for `TryUpdateModelAsync`, I realize that I'd essentially need to mock everything down to the metadata, which isn't proving to be straightforward.

I'm wondering if perhaps this difficulty is telling me something:  `TryUpdateModelAsync` makes it hard to test, so I should refactor the controller method to not rely on this helper.  Instead, I could add another parameter to the method for my viewmodel and decorate it with `[FromBody]`, so the model binding would happen from the post fields when present, but I would be able to pass in a view model when  testing.  However, I like the `TryUpdateModelAsync` method, because it does the busy work of merging the post fields into my view model.  The other way I can think to accomplish the merging is write my own Merge method.  Okay, no big deal, but I'd prefer not to have to do this for each entity (or reinvent the wheel writing a reflection based merger) and really, I'm wondering if I just missed the boat on how to write a unit test against this.  I could fire up a whole `TestServer`, like I do for integration tests, but I'm not sure this is the right direction and feels like I would just be complicating my unit tests further.  However, maybe it is justified in this scenario?

I've seen answers that worked with previous versions of .net mvc, where all they needed to do was mock an `IValueProvider` and attach it to the controller, but in .net core it appears the `TryUpdateModelAsync` was reworked and requires more moving parts.

In sum, I see three options:

1. Continue mocking and stubbing out all the pieces that
   `TryUpdateModelAsync` needs.  This might be a dead end, it seems to
   be so far.
2. Use `TestServer` and make this test from a little
   higher altitude using an `HttpClient`
3. Refactor this method to use
   `[FromBody]` on a view model parameter, then write my own merge
   methods for each entity, there by side stepping
   `TryUpdateModelAsync` altogether

These all have their drawbacks, so I'm hoping there's a 4th entry to this list that I don't see because I am ignorant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the source for ControllerBase, I noticed that the troublesome method in question relies on the **static** method `ModelBindingHelper.TryUpdateModelAsync` *(seriously!!!!? I thought we were more evolved by now.)*

This as you have already painfully discovered makes testing your controller some what of a bother.

> I'm wondering if perhaps this difficulty is telling me something

well stop wondering. It is. :)

Here is another option you may have over looked. Abstract/Adapt away that difficulty back to the depths from which it came.

```
public interface IModelBindingHelperAdaptor {
    Task<bool> TryUpdateModelAsync<TModel>(ControllerBase controller, TModel model) where TModel : class;
}
```

an implementation can look like this

```
public class DefaultModelBindingHelperAdaptor : IModelBindingHelperAdaptor {
    public virtual Task<bool> TryUpdateModelAsync<TModel>(ControllerBase controller, TModel model) where TModel : class {
        return controller.TryUpdateModelAsync(model);
    }
}
```

Inject the `IModelBindingHelperAdaptor` into your controller as a dependency and let it call the demon spawned method.

```
var bindingSuccess = await modelBindingHelper.TryUpdateModelAsync(this, vm);
```

You are now free to mock your abstraction without all the tight coupling, which is what I think they should have done in the first place.

Now I assume you already know to setup the necessary things in your startup to allow for the above suggestion to work so it should not be a difficult task for you to get that up and running.

Comment: Well, I like that solution - if you need to mock it, wrap it up and inject.  I agree, ControllerBase is not adhering well to the explicit dependencies principal.    I went another direction and fleshed out the HttpContext and ran into a problem that way where it didn't  throw an exception, but the model wasn't updated.  I'll leave that for another a different question.  This seems to provide a viable 4th option :)